# Interpolating function for a nested radical $y_x=\sqrt{a+y_{x-1}}$

Tags: functional-equations, interpolation, nested-radicals

Is it possible to find an explicit expression for a function, which at integer points takes values:

$$y_1=\sqrt{a}$$

$$y_2=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}$$

$$y_3=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}$$

etc.

We can take $y_0=0$. Then, defining $y$ for negative integers is not a problem:

$$y_n=\sqrt{a+y_{n-1}}$$

$$y_{n-1}=y_n^2-a$$

Thus, for $n=-1,-2,-3,\dots$ we have a quadractic map:

$$y_{-1}=-a$$

$$y_{-2}=a^2-a$$

$$y_{-3}=(a^2-a)^2-a$$

---

Now I have no idea how to define $y_x$ for $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$. We have an obvious functional equation:

> $$y_{x+1}=\sqrt{a+y_x}$$
>
> For $x \to 0$ we have $ y_x \to 0$. But how to find an explicit expression? Maybe in terms of an integral or some special functions? Or how to even approximate this function?

At $x \to 0$ we should have $ y_x \to cx$ for some constant $c$.

This task seems hopeless to me even though such things as Gamma function or general Harmonic numbers exist, despite the fact that interpolation there is not obvious at all.

---

For the special case $a=2$ @NgChungTak gave an interpolation:

$$y_{x}=2\cos \dfrac{\pi}{2^{x+1}}$$

The plots of the sequence and the function are shown below:

[image]

However this kind of function doesn't work with the other values of $a$, even for $x>0$. For $a>0$ and $x>0$ the rate of convergence increases with $a$.

We can plot normalized sequences for different $a>0$.

$$f(n)=\frac{2 y(n)}{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}$$

[image]

---

I think it makes sense to consider a [Quadratic map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html) first, since a lot of exact solutions for special cases were found for it, and then extrapolate the solutions to negative indices.

Comment: I think you'll have to settle for recursion. But you _can_ find a closed form for the limit.

Comment: I had no doubt that you knew. Was just pointing that out for the general audience. But for the expression itself, I would forget about closed form.

Comment: In particular, $a=2$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, $y_{x}=2\cos \dfrac{\pi}{2^{x+1}}$

Comment: well, in formal power series, if you move the attracting fixpoint to $0$, your transformation is conjugate to a linear map (in a unique way), and you can then interpolate in an obvious way. This also gives you power series that perform "half a step" (or other fractional steps). I have no idea how to prove anything about their radius of convergence though

Comment: if $g(x) = x^2-a$, and $z$ is the fixpoint, then you can probably define $y_k = \lim_{n \to \infty} g^{\circ n}(z - \exp((1-k)\log (z-y_n) + k\log (z-y_{n+1})))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z) = z^2-a$ with $a \neq - \frac 14$.

If $a>0$, $f$ has a repulsive fixpoint at $\tau = (1+\sqrt{1+4a})/2$ (and most of the time, the other fixpoint is repulsive too, but let's take this one). I will note $\lambda$ the derivative of $f$ at $\tau$, which is $\lambda = 2\tau$ (larger than $1$), so near this fixpoint, $f$ acts almost like the dilation $g(z) = \lambda \tau$.

On a small disk $D$ around $\tau$ we can define $f^{-1}$ such that it sends $D$ to itself, and then according to [Koenigs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function), there is a (unique) holomorphic injective function $h$ on $D$ into a small neighbourhood of $0$ such that $h(\tau) = 0, h'(\tau) = 1$, and forall $z \in D$, $h ( f^{-1} (z)) = g^{-1}(h(z))$.

Since $h$ is injective we can define $t = h^{-1}$ on $h(D)$, and then the functional equation can be put in the form $t(g(z))
 = f(t(z))$ for $z$ close enough to $\tau$.

Now, since $g$ is a simple dilation and $f$ is entire, this means $t$ has an analytic continuation to the entire complex plane. $t$ has an essential singularity at infinity, so it takes every value infinitely often (with no exception because of the functional equation).

Let $w \in \Bbb C$ be a zero of $t$. It has a corresponding sequence $(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb Z}$ defined by $y_n = t(\lambda^{-n}w)$.
Then $y_0 = 0, y_1 = \pm \sqrt a, y_2 = \pm \sqrt {a \pm \sqrt a} \ldots$ and so on.
If you choose a value for $\log \lambda$, this allows you to interpolate the sequence to all of $\Bbb C$, defined by $y_n = t(w\exp(-n\log(\lambda)))$.

Suppose two zeroes $w_1,w_2$ give rise to the same sequence. Then, by the identity theorem we have $t(w_1z) = t(w_2z)$ forall $z \in \Bbb C$, and differentiating this relation at $z=0$ gives $w_1 = w_2$.
This work for any nonzero value too, so the points $(w,y_0)$ are in a bijective correspondance with the sequences $y_n = f(y_{n+1})$ that eventually converge to $\tau$.

To compute the interpolation approximately, you can plunge into the sequence by applying $f^{-1}$, then once you are close enough to the fixpoint, approximate $f$ with $g$ to interpolate however you need, then go back by iterating $f$ :
$y_n = \lim_{m \to \infty} f^{\circ m}(\tau+\lambda^{-n}(y_m-\tau))$.
This works in theory, but you may run into precision issues for both iterations.
You may want to instead use a power series to approximate $t$ and $h$ once you're close enough to $\tau$.

If you wonder what the fractional iterates of $f^{-1}$ would look like geometrically, it seems they aren't necessarily algebraic : they should have branch points at all the critical values of $t$.

Differentiating the functional equation of $t$ gets you $g'(z).t'(g(z)) = f'(t(z)).t'(z)$, which means $\lambda t'(g(z)) = 2t(z).t'(z)$, so the critical points of $t$ are the the zeroes of $t$ (critical points of $f$) along with their images by any number of dilations.
Furthermore, $t'$ only has simple zeroes because iterating $f$ on $0$ will never loop back to $0$.

So the critical values are $0,f(0),f((0)),\ldots$, and there $t^{-1}$ (and thus all the fractional iterates, and well everything really) have a square root-like singularity.